# Spell check multiple Excel workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, spell-check

Can anyone suggest a method to spell check across multiple Excel sheets - without having to open them all and run the check manually?

I have been largely checking as I go along but I would like to run one last scan of all the documentation before it is signed off.

I want to check several workbooks, ie different files, without having to do it all individually. I have about 60 workbooks!

Comment: If VBA is acceptable, you could write some code to open each file, run spell check, save, and close the file. It's the same process but all you have to deal with is any windows that popup. However, `Ignore All` will only work on the workbook that's currently open.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on one sheet name at the bottom, select all sheets, hit F7.

Comment: or are you trying to do several workbooks?

Comment: Unless you want to do VB scripting... First create a macro. If you haven’t done this, go to view>Macros>record. Record whatever and then overwrite the code. This is the code to select all sheets:  
Sub SlcAll()
Sheets.Select
End Sub                                                                                                          
Assign a shortcut to it, like Ctrl+T (Macros>View Macros>Options)
Make sure Macro is saved to personal.xls
Then uou can move all the files to one folder. Open them all,
 Ctrl+T to select all sheets, 
F7 to spell check
Crtl+F4 to close the sheet

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Please include the information in your comments in your answer by editing your post. Comments are not considered permanent here.

Answer (score 0):

Excel cannot check spelling of a closed workbook. Therefore, code would need to be written to open the each file, check spelling, then close the file and move to the next. This rather complicated and cumbersome to develop. Not going to do that here. So, here is an alternative to get you almost to your goal.

Add the VBA below to the `ThisWorkbook` object in VBA Explorer. When you run this macro it will check spelling of all open workbooks, with exception of `PERSONAL.xlsb` to avoid confusion.

```
Sub SpellCheckOpenWorkbooks()

'LOOP SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet


For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
  If wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.xlsb" Then
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets

        sht.Cells.CheckSpelling

    Next sht
  End If
Next wb

End Sub
```

So, open the workbooks you want checked, then run the macro.

Source for loop VBA - [Loop Through All Worksheets In All Currently Open Workbooks](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/6/11/loop-through-all-worksheets-in-all-currently-open-workbooks)

*NOTE: Use at your own risk. Make sure you save your work before you start.*